# XLS0414 Error in XAML/Xamarin but everything seems to work with the datatype

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, generics

One of my XAML pages is throwing a compile error (edit: I guess it isn't a compile error since it compiles ok? Not sure what to call it exactly), XLS0414 'm:DMenuItem_Filter' was not found. I have cleaned and rebuilt my solution, and double and triple checked the namespace. What is really weird is that if I build my solution, it says it succeeded and I can even run the app and get the behavior which DMenuItem_Filter creates. I found a post which says it isn't possible to use a class with a generic as a datatype, but it still works. Should I just suppress this error and move on? Any ideas what is going on here?

I have a content page like this:

```
 <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
           BackgroundColor="Aqua">
        <StackLayout>
            <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding TheFilters}" x:Name="TheFilterCarousel"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                      BackgroundColor="Indigo">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="m:DMenuItem_Filter"> <----**** Error here****
                        <StackLayout>

                            <comp:DFilterView x:Name="DFilterView" 
                                   NextPageCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference DinderParty_Filter}, 
                                   Path=BindingContext.AnwerSelected}">
                            </comp:DFilterView>
                            
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                
            </CarouselView>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
```

DMenuItem_Filter is this class, which I recently made generic so I could pass some lamdas through it:

```
public class DMenuItem_Filter<T> : DMenuItem
    {
        private int answerSelected = 0;
        public int AnswerSelected { get { return answerSelected; } set { answerSelected = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("AnswerSelected"); } }

        private string question;
        public string Question { get { return question; } set { question = value; } }

        private string answer1;
        public string Answer1 { get { return answer1; } set { answer1 = value; } }

        private string answer2;
        public string Answer2 { get { return answer2; } set { answer2 = value; } }

        private string answer3;
        public string Answer3 { get { return answer3; } set { answer3 = value; } }

        public Command AnswerCommand1 { get; set; }
        public Command AnswerCommand2 { get; set; }
        public Command AnswerCommand3 { get; set; }


        private Func<T, bool> lambda;
        public Func<T, bool> Lambda { get { return lambda; } set { lambda = value; } }

        private Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool>> lambdas;
        public Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool>> Lambdas { get { return lambdas; } set { lambdas = value; } }

        public DMenuItem_Filter(string Q, Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool>> lams)
        {
            lambdas = lams;
            //filterData = dta;
            answerSelected = 0;
            question = Q;

            List<string> Keys = new List<string>();
            foreach (string key in lams.Keys)
            {
                Keys.Add(key);
            }
            answer1 = Keys[0];
            answer2 = Keys[1];
            answer3 = Keys[2];
            AnswerCommand1 = new Command(async () => await ExecuteAnswerCommand1());
            AnswerCommand2 = new Command(async () => await ExecuteAnswerCommand2());
            AnswerCommand3 = new Command(async () => await ExecuteAnswerCommand3());
        }

        async Task ExecuteAnswerCommand1()
        {
            AnswerSelected = 1;
            lambda = lambdas[Answer1];
            OnPropertyChanged("AnswerSelected");
            


        }

        async Task ExecuteAnswerCommand2()
        {
            AnswerSelected = 2;
            lambda = lambdas[Answer2];
            OnPropertyChanged("AnswerSelected");
            
        }

        async Task ExecuteAnswerCommand3()
        {
            AnswerSelected = 3;
            lambda = lambdas[Answer3];
            OnPropertyChanged("AnswerSelected");
        }

    }
```

Here is DFilterView:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Dinder.Controls.DFilterView">
    <Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="AnswerSelectedLabel" Text="{Binding Question}"   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="30"></Label>
       
            <Button Text="{Binding Answer1}" Command="{Binding AnswerCommand1}" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"></Button>
        <Button Text="{Binding Answer2}" Command="{Binding AnswerCommand2}" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"></Button>
        <Button Text="{Binding Answer3}" Command="{Binding AnswerCommand3}" Clicked="Button_Clicked" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"></Button>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class DFilterView : ContentView
    {

        public static readonly BindableProperty AnswerChosenProperty = BindableProperty.Create("AnswerChosen", typeof(int), typeof(DFilterView), 0);

        public static readonly BindableProperty NextPageCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create("NextPageCommand", typeof(Command), typeof(DFilterView), new Command(async () => await DoNothing()));


        public Command NextPageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return (Command)GetValue(NextPageCommandProperty);
            }
            set { SetValue(NextPageCommandProperty, value); }
        }


        public DFilterView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private static async Task DoNothing()
        {

        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ((Command)GetValue(NextPageCommandProperty)).Execute(null);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by extending my DMenuItem_Filter class like so, extracting the generic aspects of the class:

```
    public class DMenuItem_Filter<T> : DMenuItem_Filter
    {

        private Func<T, bool> lambda;
        public Func<T, bool> Lambda { get { return lambda; } set { lambda = value; } }

        private Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool>> lambdas;
        public Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool>> Lambdas { get { return lambdas; } set { lambdas = value; } }

        public DMenuItem_Filter(string Q, Dictionary<string, Func<T, bool>> lams)  : base(Q,new List<string>(lams.Keys))
        {
            lambdas = lams;
        }

        public override async Task ExecuteAnswerCommand1()
        {
            await base.ExecuteAnswerCommand1();
            lambda = lambdas[Answer1];
        }
        public override async Task ExecuteAnswerCommand2()
        {
            await base.ExecuteAnswerCommand1();
            lambda = lambdas[Answer2];
        }
        public override async Task ExecuteAnswerCommand3()
        {
            await base.ExecuteAnswerCommand1();
            lambda = lambdas[Answer3];
        }
    }
```